# Is it possible to retract the lens on a Sony RX100 without turning the camera off?

Tags: sony, sony-rx100

Is it possible to retract the lens of this camera without turning the camera off?

For instance it would be nice to be able to just turn the camera on to use the WiFi transfer functionality without opening the lens. Equally, when shooting, it would be good if there was a 'sleep' timer that retracted the lens and turned off the LCD after a certain period of inactivity.

Comment: Does the owner's/user's manual mention anything about this?

Comment: In playback mode, the lens should retract (may take a few seconds).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Turn camera off, then press play button (▶). Thus camera will be turned on without opening the lens. Then press menu button to send photos through wifi etc.
- In menu settings, you can set sleep timer which will retract lenses after some time(see user manual).